# UWP - UDP connection only works over local networks

Tags: sockets, tcp, uwp, udp

I have recently been developing capabilities that are based on UDP transfer protocol, specifically using the DatagramSocket class.

This has been working very well between two machines that are both connected to the same Wifi access point (LAN), however, as soon as I leave and connect the remote machine to another access point, it is unable to connect to the sever.  Why isn't the UDP DatagramSocket that worked over LAN working beyond LAN?

(the code is written in vb.net is that matters)

Comment: Have you enabled the appropriate [Networking Capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/networking-basics)?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Thanks for the response.  Yes, I've enabled both the Internet Client & Server capabilities and the Private Network Client & Server.

Comment: Have you got any exception message? And please check your firewall configurations.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT No, I have not received any exceptions at all.  And I have tried the connection both with Firewall on and Firewall completely turned off.

Comment: Could you ping your server successfully?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I am not too sure what you mean by that, but I did a few searches and did the following steps: 1) opened Command prompt on a second device (that is connected to the same wifi network.  2) Typed in "ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", with the X's resembling the server's IP address.  3) It returned "Request timed out."

Comment: ‘Request timed out’ meant that your machine cannot connect to your server. The issue was not in your code.

Comment: I see. @XavierXie-MSFT But just to clarify, it should be possible to build a UDP server in a UWP app with the DatagramSocket class that is capable of connecting to clients beyond the LAN?

Comment: Yes. I know. I have not said that you could not be able to build your UDP UWP server. I said your problem is your local machine cannot connect to server machine.